# calling Karate framework from Rest service or spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, rest, karate

We have a scenario where the user copies csv to a shared location and based on the file, we have to call the respective karate test runner class. The problem i have is to create a test service in springboot and call karate framework test from it. I've read the csv from shared location from springboot but how to call the karate test class and pass the csv to it?

Comment: consider this as not directly supported by karate - but all the info available is in the linked q & a, all the best